# How I can send a file to receive a value back (that works for internet explorer 8-9)?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Good day colleagues, I am having a technical problem, I hope you can help me because I've invested a lot of time.

I have a list of files with some descriptions as document type and description in a table, the first column is used for an ID in which it is 0 is a new file, I have another column for a

The form you need to do are: 
-1 You can add new files on the client side and not save until give click on the button "Save". (record does not exist on the server). 
-2 Update files (uploading a new file in a record that exists on the server) 
-3 To upload the next file by client side the "Upload" button is generated that **to give click it will have to upload the file and must receive an ID return by server side** to update the column and you to click on save it the server detect that file already on server. This is because business rules.

**VIEW**

```
<p class="options">
    <a id="attach_file">Attach File</a>
</p>
<table id="files" class="grid">
    <tr>
        <th class="id">ID</th>
        <th class="name">File</th>
        <th class="kindName">Find Of file</th>
        <th class="observations">Observations</th>
        <th class="attach">File (input)</th>
        <th class="options">options</th>
    </tr>
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Files.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td class="id">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Files[i].FileID)</td>
        <td class="name">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Files[i].Name)</td>
        <td class="kindName">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Files[i].KindOfFile.Name)</td>
        <td class="observations">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Files[i].Version.Observations)</td>
        <td class="attach">this options is only for client side when upload a new file</td>
        <td class="options">
            <a class="file_upload">Upload</a>
            <a class="file_delete">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

when the user clicks on the button "attach file" to add the following javascript code tr with the necessary data, with the option to "upload" that upload file (at server) at the time

**JavaScript**

```
function GetTR(index, _ID, _FileName, _KindOfFile, _Observations) {
    var tr = "<tr>";

    tr += '<td class="id"><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field FileID must be a number." data-val-required="The FileID field is required." id="Files_' + index + '__FileID" name="Files[' + index + '].FileID" type="text" value="' + _ID + '" readonly></td>';
    tr += '<td class="name"><input data-val="true" data-val-length="La longitud Máxima es de 250" data-val-length-max="50" data-val-required="El Nombre es requerido" id="Files_' + index + '__Name" name="Files[' + index + '].Name" type="text" value="' + _FileName + '" readonly></td>';
    tr += '<td class="kindName"><input data-val="true" data-val-length="La longitud Máxima es de 100" data-val-length-max="50" data-val-required="El Nombre es requerido" id="Files_' + index + '__KindOfFile_Name" name="Files[' + index + '].KindOfFile.Name" type="text" value="' + _KindOfFile + '" readonly></td>';
    tr += '<td class="observations"><input id="Files_' + index + '__Version_Observations" name="Files[' + index + '].Version.Observations" type="text" value="' + _Observations + '" aria-invalid="false" class="valid" readonly></td>';
    tr += "<td class='attach'></td>";
    tr += '<td class="options">'
        + '<a class="file_upload" style="background-color:#FF9D4B;">Upload</a>'
        + '<a class="file_delete">Delete</a>'
        + '</td>';
    tr += "</tr>";

    return tr;
}
```

by **JQuery** add the selected file in a modal div and add a certain column the

> $(fileInput).attr({ "id": "Files_" + index + "__Version_FileUpload",
>   "name": "Files[" + index + "].Version.FileUpload"
>   }).appendTo(".attach:last");

you see, I use the ID and name with a nomenclature and index to match with MVC. I do this to send properties and files that occupy for the model. so you can upload multiple files to create a new one or update.

**Solution does not work in Internet Explorer**

Event to upload the file to the server and receives an ID using AJAX and FormData object. function works in Chrome but not in Internet Explorer
**share this solution in case anyone needs it**

```
var fileViewModel = GetFileViewModel($(this).closest("tr"));
var formdata = new FormData(); //FormData object
var fileInput = $(this).closest("tr").find("td.attach > input:first")[0];
// si son varios archivos iterar
if (fileInput.files != null) {
    for (i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
        formdata.append(fileInput.files[i].name, fileInput.files[i]); // attach file
        formdata.append("ViewModel", JSON.stringify(fileViewModel)); // attach object
    }
    var ctrl = $(this).closest("tr");

    $.ajax({
        url: '/ProvisionOfService/Upload',
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            $(ctrl).find("td.options > a.file_upload").remove();
            // actualizar ID
            if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
                $(ctrl).find("td.id > input").val(data[0]);
            }
            $("#Loading").hide();
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            console.log(xhr, status);
            alert("error");
            $("#Loading").hide();
        }
    });
}
```

C# Controller and action

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Upload()
{
    string msg = null;
    List<int> FileIDs = new List<int>();
    try
    {
        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            // get Object from the client
            string JsonObject = Request.Form["ViewModel"];
            FileViewModel _file = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileViewModel>(JsonObject);

            // Save file and object
            string Path = "/Content/files/" + _file.Transaction.TransactionID + "/";
            string FullPath = Server.MapPath(Path);
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(FullPath))
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(FullPath);
            _file.Version.FileUpload.SaveAs(FullPath + _file.Version.Name);
            _file.Version.Path = Path;
            _file.Versions.Add(_file.Version);

            // Save record and get IDs
            List<FileViewModel> files = new List<FileViewModel>();
            files.Add(_file);
            FileIDs = _FileService.AddFiles(files);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        msg = ex.InnerException == null ? ex.Message : ex.InnerException.Message;
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(msg) && FileIDs.Count > 0)
        return Json(FileIDs);
    else
    {
        return Json(msg);
    }
}
```

**RESEARCH**

Send file via a form, this works only to send the file but not for replies (IDs) =(

```
if (document.getElementById('upload_form') == null)
    $('body').append('<form id="upload_form" name="upload_form" action="/ProvisionOfService/Upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >');

var $upload_form = $('#upload_form');
var fileInput = $(this).closest("tr").find("td.attach > input:first")[0];
$(fileInput).appendTo($upload_form);
upload_form.submit();
```

Through Ajax thought and send a file server (driver) thought receive an object of type HttpPostedFileBase 
but I'm getting an error

**Ajax**

```
var fileInput = $(this).closest("tr").find("td.attach > input:first")[0];

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/ProvisionOfService/Upload',
    data: { file: fileInput },
    success: function (data) {
        // update ID
        if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
            $(ctrl).find("td.id > input").val(data[0]);
        }
        $("#Loading").hide();
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        console.log(xhr, status);
        alert("error");
        $("#Loading").hide();
    }
});
```

**C# Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    // code
}
```

The error I get is:

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'selectionDirection'
>   property from 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('file')
>   does not support selection.

I'm not sure this works for security reason

> **How I can send a file to receive a value back (that works for internet explorer)? (to be able to point 3)**

Comment: Well, first things first, you can't submit files via AJAX without the File API from HTML5. That means that you can only do so with modern browsers, which in the case of IE means 10+ only. If you need to support anything in the IE6-9 range, then you're out of luck.

Comment: I'm not lucky, I need it to work in IE8-9, thanks for the reply

Comment: There are some File API polyfills that try an emulate the functionality in browsers that don't support it. https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Comment: It will allow you to emulate the functionality of the File API, but not the ability to send the actual file data over via AJAX. If you have to support IE8-9, then you'll either need to do a regular form post or use a Flash or Java upload control that supports auto uploading to a backend endpoint. The communication happens through the plugin rather than JavaScript at that point.

Comment: @Ben-Robinson I was watching your suggestion of using a polyfills and Moxie has the object FormData download the moxie.js (https://github.com/moxiecode/moxie#compile-js), I included the reference and still ticking mistake the object in IE9, out there reading the documentation says it has to be compiled, and then have code for flash and silverlight. .. am I missing something?

Comment: File API polyfills (moxie) does not work, send in the null Request.Files =´(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieves already solve this problem, the solution was: 
-add an additional form to the body: 
  + the action property to point to my controller + action 
  + the target property to my iframe 
  + add this file input type = "file" to form 
-make one sumbit 
- In the controller + action 
ActionResult return (to be loaded in the iframe) and rescue files with Request.Files [0] 
- In the event of the iframe to emulate the success and error event to rescue the values

```
$(document).on("click", ".Archivo_Upload", function () {
    // inyectamos el iframe para obtener el resultado
    // el form al que se le dara sumbit contendra el archivo y el input hidden para parametros adicionales
    if (document.getElementById('upload_form') == null)
        $('body').append('<iframe id="upload_frame" name="upload_frame"></iframe>'
            + '<form id="upload_form" name="upload_form" action="/ProvisionOfService/Upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_frame" >'
            + '<input id="fileViewModel" type="hidden" name="ViewModel" value="" />'
            + '</form>');

        // obtenemos el form
        var $upload_form = $('#upload_form');
        // obtenemos el archivo que se adjunto
        var fileInput = $(this).closest("tr").find("td.attach > input:first")[0];
        $(fileInput).appendTo($upload_form); // lo adjuntamos al form que se dara submit

        var fileViewModel = GetFileViewModel($(this).closest("tr")); // obtener objeto fileViewModel

        $('#fileViewModel').val(JSON.stringify(fileViewModel)); // agregar valor en el input
        $upload_form.submit(); // enviar form

        var ctrl = $(this).closest("tr"); // obtener el control tr para que este dispnible en el load del frame

        // evento load del frame simula el success y el error event
        $("#upload_frame").load(function () {
            var result = $("#upload_frame").contents().find("body").text();
            try {
                var ID = parseInt(result);
                $(ctrl).find("td.id > input").val(ID);
                $(ctrl).find("td.options > a.Archivo_Upload").remove();
                $("#Loading").hide();
            } 
            catch(ex) {
                // si esta vacio el result
                if (result == "")
                    result = ex.message;

                // mostrar error
                $("#msgFiles").text(result).addClass("error").show();
            }
            finally {
                // limpiar iframe y form
                $('#upload_frame').remove();
                $('#upload_form').remove();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as a suggestion, I had a similar problem accommodating a JSON ajax call when it needed to work in all browsers plus IE8. I'm not familiar with exactly how it all worked, but the solution we ended up with was to use JQuery. With a little gentle coaxing it has accommodated all our browser requirements with something similar to the following...

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: http://myAjaxTestURL,
    dataType: 'text',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {

    var returnData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    if(returnData.length>0) {
        for(var i=0;i<returnData.length;i++){
            var myHappyObject = returnData[i];
            //do something with my returned object
        }
        } else {
            //do something else
        }
    },
    error: function(request, status, error) {
        //error processing
    }
});
```

It might be worth a look if you can't find anything more suitable.

Note: Just to add, I haven't tried this with posting files.